# Xcode 6, Yosemite Mac app help book: topic unavailable

Tags: xcode, cocoa, operating-system, osx-yosemite

I am attempting to make a simple non-localized help book for my Cocoa application. I've made a .help  file with the structure described in the somewhat out-of-date Apple Help Programming Guide.
When I run my app in the debugger from Xcode, the help item is correctly listed under the help menu. But selecting it just brings up a dialogue with "The selected topic is currently unavailable".

Opening the help bundle and going to the title page html file (in Safari) correctly navigates the structure of the help folder. This is only 3 pages. It seems like the help viewer is not getting to the title page. What is the correct structure of the help bundle and the related plist values for the help viewer to work?

I have:

`contents/`
Info.plist

Resources/

English.lproj/

title page.html, help index, pigs folder, sty folder etc

thanks

r

Comment: I ended up using a third party helper app "HelpTemplate Creator" from Valli Software.

Comment: This disappeared at my end upon using a simple help book from an other app as a template, altering the property lists as well as other files (the Apple docs are alright), and [clearing the Help Viewer's property lists](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/helpviewer.html#Anchor-Reset-35882). Note that [if the console (Console.app) reports that the help book with given ID cannot be found, then toying around with the relevant key-value pairs (eg. CFBundleName) should work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926232/debugging-help-book-the-selected-topic-is-currently-unavailable).